# Conditional attributes with jsonapi-serializers throwing TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, jsonapi-serialize

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project with ruby-2.6.0 and Rails 6. i am working on api part, i have used jsonapi-serializers gem in my app. I want to add conditional attribute in serializer.

Controller:

```
class OrderDetailsController < Api::V1::ApiApplicationController
    before_action :validate_token
    
  def show
    user = User.find_by_id(@user_id)
    order_details = user.order_details.where(id: params[:id])&.first
    render json: JSONAPI::Serializer.serialize(order_details, context: { order_detail: true })
  end
end
```

Serializer:

```
class OrderDetailSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer

  TYPE = 'Order Details'

  attribute :order_number
  attribute :price
  attribute :quantity
  attribute :order_status

  attribute :ordered_date, if: Proc.new { |record|
    context[:order_detail] == true
  }
end
```

So here i am passing the 'order_detail' from controller inside context.I am getting the below error:-

```
TypeError (#<Proc:0x00007fe5d8501868@/app_path/app/serializers/order_detail_serializer.rb:46> is not a symbol nor a string):
```

I have followed the conditional attributes as mentioned on the [jsonapi-serializer](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer) and have tried to make my 'ordered_date' attribute conditional but it's not working.

Please guide me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You access `context` but it seems not defined. From the documentation

> The record and any params passed to the serializer are available inside the Proc as the first and second parameters, respectively.

```rb
class OrderDetailSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer

  TYPE = 'Order Details'

  attribute :order_number
  attribute :price
  attribute :quantity
  attribute :order_status

  attribute :ordered_date, if: Proc.new { |record, params|
    params[:context][:order_detail]
  }
end
```

You also don't need to check for `== true` as the parameter is already a boolean.

If that doesn't work, you can always add a puts or debugger in your Proc to have a look what is happening in the Proc.

```rb
class OrderDetailSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer

  TYPE = 'Order Details'

  attribute :order_number
  attribute :price
  attribute :quantity
  attribute :order_status

  attribute :ordered_date, if: Proc.new { |record, params|
    puts record.inspect
    puts params.inspect
    true
  }
end
```

Comment: Hi @Christian Thanks for your reply but i am still getting the same error...seems my Proc is not compiling/executing properly. I even tried with lamda but still the error is same.

Comment: Is there a way to call any custom serializer by passing the name of the serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example for [conditional attributes](https://github.com/jsonapi-serializer/jsonapi-serializer#conditional-attributes), you simply need to pass `params` as a second parameter, so:

in controller:

```rb
render json: JSONAPI::Serializer.serialize(order_details, { params: { order_detail: true }})
```

in serializer:

```rb
attribute :ordered_data, if: Proc.new { |record, params|
  params[:order_detail]
}
```